# How do I build or request a Struts 2 build into Maven?

Tags: struts2

I work on a Maven project that uses Struts 2 and recently I became aware of some security vulnerabilities in Struts2 which are apparently fixed in version 2.3.26.

Unfortunately for me, the highest Struts2 version that is built to Maven is 2.3.24.1, which matches the version downloadable on the Struts2 ["Download a Release"](https://struts.apache.org/download.cgi) page as of just now.

I'd be happy to build v 2.3.26 to Maven if that's something the community can do, or request it from the right person otherwise, but I haven't been able to figure out what to do so far.

I believe [this](https://github.com/apache/struts/releases/tag/STRUTS_2_3_26) is the source code and tag for Struts 2.3.26.

Comment: @RomanC, [s2-029](http://struts.apache.org/docs/s2-029.html) and [s2-030](http://struts.apache.org/docs/s2-030.html)

Comment: Unclear what are you asking. It will be available from maven central once it is released. Otherwise you can build it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Releases `2.3.26` and `2.3.27` had bugs: however,

> Struts [**`2.3.28`**](http://struts.apache.org/downloads.html) is available from today.

It corrects both of the vulnerabilities you're talking about.

That said, if you need to build Struts2 from source code, or nightly build, or whatever, you need to follow the guides linked in [this page](https://struts.apache.org/builds.html).